# Why easyphp stop all apache processes on severals PC?

Tags: windows, apache, process, easyphp

on some Windows PC, when I have both easyPHP and a standalone apache service configured on another network port and with a specific service name, I have a problem : when I stop easyphp, the other apache is stopped too.

The problem do not occur on all PC I have, but seems very strange to me.
Any idea?

more information after answer from Radar : my process have a special name (ecapache), but easyphp does not seems to use process but rather lauch directly the servers.

Thanks 
Cédric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe how it's killing it is that it's finding all processes called "apache" or similar and just killing them, regardless of if it 'owns' it or not.

Answer (score 0):

i think Both are integrated together, i was not occur in all PC because of port number.